# Puppeteer file upload with webkitdirectory

Tags: node.js, webkit, puppeteer

I have written a page with a form which has a file input field with `webkitdirectory`. Now I am trying to test it with Puppeteer. There appears to be a `uploadFile('path/to/file')` method which I was hoping would also accept directories. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to do so.

This is the line in the test file:

```
await input.uploadFile('/path/to/directory')
```

When on the nodejs side I print the file (which is handled with formidable) I get this output:

```
File {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  size: 0,
  path:
   '/tmp/uploads-dir--aohyI0/upload_9f55c1ec641fac3902faccf665cfac35',
  name: '',
  type: 'application/octet-stream',
  hash: null,
  lastModifiedDate: null,
  _writeStream: null }
```

However when I manually upload the directory with chrome by hand I get this:

```
File {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  size: 0,
  path:
   '/tmp/uploads-dir--dbCZZG/upload_ec20a6ffc079a3cba92d8114b7418527',
  name:
   'path/to/myfile.txt',
  type: 'application/octet-stream',
  hash: null,
  lastModifiedDate: null,
  _writeStream: null }
```

As you can see the name is blank on the first one and I do not receive any actual files.

Is there any way to test forms with `webkitdirectory` with Puppeteer?